What circumstances guarantee a p-adic affine conjugacy map will be a rational function?
Let $\Bbb Q_p$ be a p-adic field and let any element $x$ of $\Bbb Q_p$ be associated with a unique element of $\Bbb Z_p$ via the quotient / equivalence relation $\forall n\in\Bbb Z:p^nx\sim x$
Then in $\Bbb Q_2$, for any pair $a,b$ of $2$-adic units there is a unique canonical homeomorphism $T_{a,b}(x)$ which fixes $f(0)=0$ and topologically conjugates $f_{a,b}(x)=ax+b\cdot 2^{\nu_2(x)}$ to $f_{1,-1}(x)=x-2^{\nu_2(x)}$
A proof of this is given in Lagarias and Bernstein 2019, although note that my form differs slightly from theirs in that mine satisfies $2f(x)=f(2x)$ and therefore respects the rays of the quotient I define above, whereas theirs is defined absent the quotient map.  Nevertheless, both yield the same $T_{a,b}(x):\Bbb Q_2\to\Bbb Q_2$ and in both cases the conjugacy map $T$ also obeys the rays of the quotient, so $pT_{a,b}(x)=T_{a,b}(px)$. (here $p=2$).
I'm sure similar holds for fields in which $p\neq2$ although additional conditions may be required to guarantee uniqueness of $T$.
Definition
Let a function be rational if it maps every periodic p-adic number to a periodic p-adic number.
Question
For which $a,b,p$ will $T_{a,b}(x):\Bbb Q_p\to\Bbb Q_p$ be a rational function?
Observations
$\Bbb Z_p$ is a sufficient set for any answer. The answer for $\Bbb Q_p$ follows trivially.
There are fairly obvious solutions $(a,b)$ such as $\pm1,\pm1$ for any prime $p$
It seems to me that in order to define rational functions we need to define some topological space or set which is "sufficient" in some sense to characterise the "boundary" between periodic and aperiodic numbers, and perhaps show that it remains unchanged by $T$, or that $T$ contracts it into the periodic numbers.
I'd be interested in any answer which can "grow" the set $a=\pm1, b=\pm1$ no matter how minimally, or which can elucidate upon how I might realise the idea of the boundary between periodic and aperiodic numbers, or link(s) to any relevant material.
